# Filter repetitive sequences on Python

Tags: python, filter, sequence

I have a txt file like this:

```
GAACACGAAGGACGC
GAACACGAAGGACGC
GAACACGAAGGACGC
GAACACGAAGGACGC
GAACACGAAGGACGC
TCTAAGTAGTCAAAA
TCTAAGTAGTCAAAA
TCTAAGTAGTCAAAA
TCTAAGTAGTCAAAA
TCTAAGTAGTCAAAA
TCTAAGTAGTCAAAA
ACGGTGGGAATAAGA
ACGGTGGGAATAAGA
ACGGTGGGAATAAGA
ACGGTGGGAATAAGA
ACGGTGGGAATAAGA
GGGGCGATAATTTGC
GGGGCGATAATTTGC
GGGGCGATAATTTGC
GGGGCGATAATTTGC
GGGGCGATAATTTGC
GGGGCGATAATTTGC
```

and I would like to filter out sequences that are repeated six times and save them in a txt file. How could I do it on Python? Sorry if it's a dumb question.

Thank you in advance

I tried:

```
ids = open('IDs.txt', 'r')

for id in ids:
    if id is ...
```

The big problem is that the txt file has more than 100k unique sequences.. I can't go one by one.. that's why I'm stuck here

Comment: Show your attempts please.

Comment: Use `collections.Counter`

Comment: where is your code ? where you stack?

Comment: Of course, it's NOT a dumb question but there's no sign of your attempts. So, this way it's too broad to answer. Please also include what you've tried so far and the point of failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
lst = []
lst6 = []
with open(r'data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        lst.extend(l.split())

for k,v in Counter(lst).items():
    if v == 6:
        lst6.append(k)

with open(r'data6.txt', 'w') as f:
    for x in lst6:
        f.write(x)
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much!